# change domain proxy_pass to ip

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I used reverse proxy but seeing the nginx log it changes the address to ip and it doesn't work because the destination server is vhost and it only works with domains.

```
location  = /video {
    resolver 8.8.8.8;
    if ( $arg_net != "" ) {
        proxy_pass https://$arg_net.serverA.com;
    }
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
```

I see in the nginx log

```
... upstream: "https://[2a02:2518:4:3875::d]:443/video?net=...
```

How can I use it only with the domain??

Answer (score 1):

That's why `proxy_set_header` exists, and you need

```
proxy_pass https://$arg_net.serverA.com;
proxy_set_header Host "$arg_net.serverA.com";
```

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/#passing-request-headers